# Detecting boilerplate in text samples

Tags: text-mining, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a corpus of unstructured text that, due to a concatenation from different sources, has boilerplate metadata that I would like to remove. For example:

> DESCRIPTION PROVIDED BY AUTHOR: The goal of my ...
>
> Author provided: The goal of my ...
>
> The goal of my ... END OF TRANSCRIPT
>
> The goal of my ... END, SPONSORED BY COMPANY XYZ
>
> The goal of my ... SPONSORED: COMPANY XYZ, All rights reserved, date: 10/21

This boilerplate can be assumed to occur in beginning or end of each sample. What are some robust methods for wrangling this out of the data?

Comment: IMHO `data-wrangling` should be a tag here, but I lack the reputation to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started. Phrase length is determined by the range() function. Basically this tokenizes and creates n-grams. Then it counts each token. Tokens with a high mean over all documents (occurs often across documents) is printed out in the last line.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np
import nltk

text = """DESCRIPTION PROVIDED BY AUTHOR: The goal of my a...
Author provided: The goal of my b...
The goal of my c... END OF TRANSCRIPT
The goal of my d... END SPONSORED BY COMPANY XYZ
The goal of my e... SPONSORED: COMPANY XYZ All rights reserved date: 10/21
"""

def todocuments(lines):
    for line in lines:
        words = line.lower().split(' ')
        doc = ""
        for n in range(3, 6):
            ts = nltk.ngrams(words, n)
            for t in ts: doc = doc + " " + str.join('_', t) 
        yield doc

cv = CountVectorizer(min_df=.5)

fit = cv.fit_transform(todocuments(text.splitlines()))
vocab_idx = {b: a for a, b in cv.vocabulary_.items()}

means = fit.mean(axis=0)
arr = np.squeeze(np.asarray(means))
[vocab_idx[idx] for idx in np.where(arr > .95)[0]]
# ['goal_of_my', 'the_goal_of', 'the_goal_of_my']
```

Comment: tf-idf is a good idea, but it would require me to know beforehand the size of the boilerplate text. I guess I could keep taking steps up and threshold them,

Comment: This uses counts, not tf-idf. The idf would diminish a token value if it appeared in many documents. Also if you had a frequent text 'a b c d e' where each letter represents a word and you only decided to have a maximum of 3-word phrases then a_b_c, b_c_d, and c_d_e would also be frequent. So, it may not be necessary to know the maximum length of frequent phrases in advance.